# How do I import multiple font weights in next.js13?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, google-font-api

I am trying to import the Poppins font weights from `@next/fonts/google`. But I need to define the font weights because Poppins is not a variable font.

This is what I have so far.

```
const poppins = Poppins(
{
    weight: `100`|`200`|`300`|`400`|`500`|`600`|`700`|`800`|`900`,
  },
s)
```

This is the Error am getting.

```
./app/layout.jsx
Error: 
  x Font loader values must be explicitly written literals.
   ,----
 6 | weight: `100 | 200 | 300| 400 | 500 | 600 | 700 | 800 | 900`,
   :         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   `----

  x Font loader values must be explicitly written literals.
   ,----
 8 | s
   : ^
   `----
```

Answer (score 0):

This appears to work:

```js
import { Roboto } from '@next/font/google';

const font900 = Roboto({
    weight: '900',
});

const font100 = Roboto({
    weight: '100',
});
```

Comment: Is their  a way to  import them in an array.

Answer (score 0):

This how I do it,

```js
import { poppins } from '@next/font/google'

const poppins = poppins({
  weight: [`100`,`200`,`300`,`400`,`500`,`600`,`700`,`800`,`900`],
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Next.js 13.1.5 and this did work fine:

```
weight: ["100", "200", "300", "400", "500", "600", "700", "800", "900"]
```